# How can an injected superclass Bean get the wrong instance ( subclass Bean instance) injected?

Tags: java, inheritance, ejb, javabeans, code-injection

**Problem:**
I had some unexpected behaviour when injecting a Bean(In a filter) with 2 subclasses which I injected in two other classes (Servlets). Now the injected superclass could hold a reference to a subclass instance at runtime (changeing with each container restart).

I must have made a serious mistake but I can't quite figure out what exactly.

**Additional information:**

I use Java EE6

**Class structure:**

In the filter I inject the super class which holds a random instance to one of the subclasses or the superclass:

```
@EJB
private ClientLogger clientLogger;
```

The super class been starts like this:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ClientLogger implements HcpEntityBeanLogger<Client> {

private Client client;

public ClientLogger(){
}

....

}
```

This subclass bean I inject in one of my Servlets:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AdminClientLogger extends ClientLogger {

public AdminClientLogger(){
}
...
}
```

**Solution attempt:**

So as far as I understand the subclass which gets last injected will be the instance referenced by clientLogger, but why, why can't I have 3 different instances and use inheritance here?

**Edit:**
I faced this problem again when injecting multiple query beans which all implement the same interface, all of them would hold a reference to the same instance.

The solution was to add beanName wenn injecting the interface with EJB

```
@EJB(beanName="name of your bean class or name specified in @Stateless(name=".."))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically this happens when you forget to reference to the concrete sub class. Then the container will apparently just inject the same instance of one of the concrete classes;

There are a number of ways to reference the concrete class:

lookup (example from @NiranjanBhat)

```
 @EJB(lookup="java:global/rest/AdminClientLogger")
  private ClientLogger clientLogger;
```

beanName

```
@EJB(beanName="name of your bean class or name specified in @Stateless(name=".."))
```

there is also

- name
- beanInterface
- mappedName

  how to use them you can take [from the java docs about EJB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html#description())

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lookup attribute on the @EJB annotation and get the required subclass injected. E.g.

```
     @EJB(lookup="java:global/rest/AdminClientLogger")
      private ClientLogger clientLogger;
```

Obviously you would have to change the JNDI lookup path in the example above.